# How to give 2nd input to a '.exe' file after the Process.start method is called?

Tags: c#

I have to execute a '.exe' file which produces a output and asks for another input again. I am able to run the first part but I am not able to pass the second parameter to complete the process.

Here is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Context.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "xyz";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: What do you meant by second parameter?

Comment: As u can see I start the process with a parameter. The exe file executes the code and asks for another input while execution. Make sense?

Comment: Yes. Both of the answers below would work then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [StandardInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) in conjunction with [RedirectStandardInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can pass any data that a user would enter on the command line using this StandardInput `StreamWriter` object.  If this application has a user interface, you may need to do something else entirely.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Context.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "xyz";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
var p = Process.Start(startInfo);

// Write whatever data you need to send to the application here.
p.StandardInput.Write("y");
```

Comment: I think the code should be startInfo.RedirectStandardInput=true; Still accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `startInfo.RedirectStandardInput`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details